# Why I am unable to inject angular controller?

Tags: angularjs

Today I decided to change the method I am injecting my controller. I managed to use "$inject Annotation", as explained [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di).

```
NetworkInterfaceDetailedViewController.$inject['$scope', '$routeParams', 'ActionDispatcher', 'HttpRequestDispatcher', 'HttpResponseHandlerFactory'];
```

I tried to inject my controller and I got this error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'HttpResponseHandlerFactory' of undefined NetworkInterfaceDetailedViewController.js:105
(anonymous function)
```

I wonder what could be the problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should assign, you forgot the `=`.

```js
NetworkInterfaceDetailedViewController.$inject = ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'ActionDispatcher', 'HttpRequestDispatcher', 'HttpResponseHandlerFactory'];
```

Comment: You must assign an `$inject` variable with the injections array. You are missing the `=`. See `.$inject = ['$scope'` instead of `.$inject['$scope'`.